# CSS file not found

Tags: css, django, static

I am going crazy with linking stylesheet file to my 'base.html' template which I use in my whole project. 
here is path to file I want link:

> C:\forum_project\static\main\css\style.css

Below is code snippet from 'base.html' from head section.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Django Developers Forum</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}">
```

As you can see the last line is attempt to derive from this stylesheet.

I am getting following information in console, when browser tries to send GET request for stylesheet.

> [16/Apr/2017 23:55:14] "GET /static/main/css/style.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404
>   1670

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to only use `href="css/style.css"` if your document is in the `main` folder.

Comment: what is path 'base.html'?

Comment: 'base.html' lives in template dir in 'main' app precisely 'C:\forum_project\main\templates\base.html'

Comment: there is not folder 'static' in path 'base.html'?

Comment: i don't understand what you've said

Comment: which is correct? C:\forum_project\main\templates\base.html OR C:\forum_project\static\main\templates\base.html?

Comment: first one, my templates aren't located in static directory

Comment: see my post,i hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove final slash to url:

href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}

I would suggest to you to move bootstrap and jquery including tags inside the body, just before the body closing tag.

Comment: heh, everyone is answering this at the same time.

Comment: idk, something magical happend.anyway it is really strange because the same error occurs, still waiting for help

Answer (score 0):

> C:\forum_project\main\templates\base.html
>
> C:\forum_project\static\main\css\style.css

**Use this code :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../static/main/css/style.css">
```